# Android: How do I make sure not to remove the Google safesearch settings even after the entire browser history is cleared?

Tags: android-9.0-pie

It is very important for me to make sure that I keep the block active and that I cannot remove it with a simple clearing of the history.
I have no idea how to do it.

I know the question here is off-topic but I don't know the section where I can post this type of question. So I ask you if you can kindly point me to the right section. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem activating the "DNS over HTTPS" feature in the Chrome app, with this url: https://doh.cleanbrowsing.org/doh/family-filter/
This is the guide link: https://cleanbrowsing.org/guides/dnsoverhttps